# Any idea of storm door brand?

Tags: doors, hinges, storm-door

I have an older storm door, no idea how old. Pretty sure it needs a new hinge rail / z-bar. There is no label on it ANYWHERE. The glass has a marking for "Guardian, Geneve NY". It is a full view with the glass and screen that can be changed out. The clips to hold the glass in are clear plastic with metal thumb screws. I found an identifier tool on Andersen and they don't seem to have used plastic clips. On mine the hinges attach to the door with 3 screws, but the ones on the Andersen site all seem to have 2 screws. I can't find replacement hinge rails for the other brands, or at least not with clear images. I'll consider a new door, but except for a sag on one side it is in pretty solid condition. We are going to sell, and since it's a condo it's preferable to repair instead of replace. Our son is living there now, so if we could fix it we would because it lets in light and air, but right now the gap on the top left lets in bugs and out A/C.
Hoping I did add both photos of screws and clip.

[image: hinge screws]
[image: clips on window panel]

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: She wants to know the manufacturer and model of the door so she can order replacement parts.

Comment: Have you tried contacting "Guardian" in "Geneve, NY" to determine if they're the manufacturer, seller or installer of the door in question? Even if they only installed it, they might have someone who could identify it, or know that they sold particular brands during particular years that may help you narrow down your search.

Comment: I want to figure out the brand so I can ask if the mfg offers replacement hinge rail.  Guardian, unfortunately is just the glass mfg.